# How to drag and drop a colored circle into a canvas in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I have created an ellipse object which I can fill through a color combobox.
Now I need to be able to click(and hold) the circle, drag my cursor to a canvas and when I release my mousebutton a new circle should be drawn at that place, with the same dimensions and color as the circle I clicked.

I think I'm doing something wrong in the Drop event.

```
    private Ellipse dragCircle = new Ellipse();

    private void eBallColor_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        dragCircle = (Ellipse)sender;
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            DataObject dragColor = new DataObject("theColor", dragCircle.Fill);
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(dragCircle, dragColor, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
    }

    private void Ellipse_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Ellipse circle = (Ellipse)sender;
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("theColor"))
        {
            Brush draggedColor = (Brush)e.Data.GetData("theColor");
            circle.Fill = draggedColor;
            dragCircle.Fill = Brushes.White;
            Point pos = e.GetPosition(canvasCard);
            double posX = pos.X;
            double posY = pos.Y;
            Canvas.SetLeft(dragCircle, posX);
            Canvas.SetTop(dragCircle, posY);
            canvasCard.Children.Add(dragCircle);
        }
    }
```

Comment: *Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results*

Comment: Please post your code; users on SO are not supplied with crystal balls.

Comment: Here is your solution: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859.aspx

Comment: @devhedgehog that link doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @amitjha choose .net version 4 and it will load